# toxresult_upload permission in devpi index

Tags: python, devpi

I am using the Python [devpi](https://devpi.net/docs/devpi/devpi/stable/%2Bd/index.html) server, and when I create an index, it adds a default a setting `acl_toxresult_upload=:ANONYMOUS:`, but I cannot find out what it means.

When I view the index in the web interface, it shows:

```
permissions

toxresult_upload
    Special: ANONYMOUS 

upload
    Users: my-user
```

I googled it, but could not find any explanation of what it means.  The only thing I could find was a [python test](https://github.com/devpi/devpi/blob/master/server/test_devpi_server/test_permissions.py) that indicates it has something to do with uploading tests, but I'm not sure what that means regarding a Pypi index.

```
    # anonymous may upload tests
    assert with_user(permissionrequest, None).has_permission(
        'toxresult_upload', StageACL(stage, False))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`devpi` supports running tests for an uploaded package with `tox` on the client side. The process is roughly the following:

1. create the dist (e.g. `python setup.py sdist`). For tests to work, the distribution must include the test scripts and the `tox.ini` config.
2. upload the dist to `devpi`, e.g.

   ```
   devpi upload --index hoefling/dev dist/mypkg-0.1.tar.gz
   ```
3. run the tests via

   ```
   devpi test --index hoefling/dev mypkg
   ```

   This will download the dist from the specified index and start the test run as configured in `tox.ini`.
4. once the tests finish, `devpi-client` will upload the test results to the server so they can be viewed anytime via the web UI:
   [image]
   When clicking on the `tests` link, you will land on the page showing the test run overview:

[image]
By clicking on the links referring to the separate test runs, you can inspect the test run logs in details.

Now, `acl_toxresult_upload`, similar to `acl_upload`, is the list of users that are allowed to upload test results to that index. `acl_toxresult_upload=:ANONYMOUS:` means that anyone can run `devpi test --index your_index yourpkg` and upload the test results. If you want to restrict the access, do it the same way you restrict the package upload access:

```
$ devpi index your_index acl_toxresult_upload=me,admin,ci-bot
```

Docs: [devpi test: testing an uploaded package](https://devpi.net/docs/devpi/devpi/latest/+d/quickstart-releaseprocess.html#devpi-test-testing-an-uploaded-package).