# devpi: manually upload toxresult.json

Tags: python, tox, devpi

I currently have a Jenkins pipeline which builds and tests my python package using [tox](https://pypi.org/project/tox/). If all unittests pass, it will be uploaded to my local devpi index.

Using `devpi test <mypackage>` I can attach the test results to the release file on the index.
But this will download the already built package again, repeat all of the already passed test suites defined in the `tox.ini` file and only then upload the results in form of a `toxresult.json`.

Is there any way to directly upload the `toxresult.json` alongside the release files? 
According to the [quickstart](https://devpi.net/docs/devpi/devpi/stable/+doc/quickstart-releaseprocess.html#devpi-test-testing-an-uploaded-package) and the [documentation of test command](https://devpi.net/docs/devpi/devpi/stable/+doc/userman/devpi_commands.html#cmdref-test) there seems to be no command line option, and neither in the [upload](https://devpi.net/docs/devpi/devpi/stable/+doc/userman/devpi_commands.html#cmdref-upload) command.

Of course I could change my Jenkins pipeline to skip the tests before uploading and then build, upload and test the package using devpi. If the `devpi test` command fails I can remove the package from the index.
But I would rather not upload a package with failing tests in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The anonymous uploads

It's relatively easy if you allow the anonymous user to upload test results (which is the default setting IIRC). Make a `POST` request to the URL of the uploaded dist, passing `tox` results as JSON payload. Example:

```
$ curl -i \
    -H "content-type: application/json" \
    -X POST \
    --data-binary "@/tmp/toxreport.json" \
    http://my-server/myuser/myindex/+f/19b/d3544d03b1716/mypkg-1.0.tar.gz
```

On success, you should get a result similar to

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 143
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 08 Jan 2020 15:48:32 GMT
Server: waitress
X-Devpi-Api-Version: 2
X-Devpi-Master-Uuid: d800735d04a14c2d9bde920149cb8dbc
X-Devpi-Serial: 42
X-Devpi-Server-Version: 5.3.1
X-Devpi-Uuid: d800735d04a14c2d9bde920149cb8dbc

{
  "result": "myuser/myindex/+f/19b/d3544d03b1716/mypkg-1.0.tar.gz.toxresult-20200108154832-0",
  "type": "toxresultpath"
}
```

You can find the target URL in the `File` column of the files table on the project page. Or query the JSON API and filter the results, e.g.

```
$ devpi getjson /myuser/myindex/mypkg | jq -r '[ .result[] | .["+links"][] | .href ]'
```

#### Authenticated uploads

`devpi` uses basic auth, so simply pass the base64-encoded credentials in the `Authorization: Basic` header. Example, with `curl` again:

```
$ curl -i \
    --user myuser:mypass \
    -H "content-type: application/json" \
    -X POST \
    --data-binary "@/tmp/toxreport.json" \
    http://my-server/myuser/myindex/+f/19b/d3544d03b1716/mypkg-1.0.tar.gz
```

If you need details on the test upload authentication, check out my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53620574/2650249).

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping that there would be a ready-made devpi extension implementing what you sketched out here, but at least that's not too hard to implement myself.